# Tabulator JS groupHeaderDownload how to create cells in Download

Tags: javascript, excel, download, tabulator

How can I create extra cells in my Excel export? I use groupHeaderDownload, this works but it only generates a string in the first column in the Excel sheet.
I am searching for a way to generate an extra cell, and an extra row.
I tried to pass arrays and an object but everything gets transformed to a single string.
Example:

```
groupHeaderDownload: function(value, count, data, group){
return [{ Nr:data[0].nr},{ Description:data[0].om}];
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add extra rows of data to your download then i would suggest that you add them to your table using the `addRow` function before your then trigger the `download` function, you could then remove it after if you dont want it available generally:

```js
var row = table.addRow({name:"Billy Bob", age:"12"}, true); //add new row to the top of the table
table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx"); //download table
row.delete(); //remove row after download
```

If you want a column to only show up in a download then in the columns definition you should set the `visible` option to `false` and the `download` option to true, which will cause the column to only show up in downloads:

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", visible:false, download:true},
```

Comment: If this was helpful, would you mind marking it as the answer to make it easier for other people to find. thanks :)